# Convert CTE query in MySQL 5 .7?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i have this table named products:

```
Create Table Products(
  ProductId Int,
  ParentId  Int,
)

Insert Products
Select 2, 3
Union All
Select 1, 2
Union All
Select 3, 4
Union All
Select 4, 5
Union All
Select 6, 5
Union All
Select 8, 7
Union All
Select 10, 9
Union All
Select 12, 11
Union All
Select 13, 6
```

And then i run this Cte Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT ProductId AS ROOTID, ParentId AS ProductId
FROM Products
WHERE ProductId=1
UNION ALL
SELECT c.ROOTID, f.ParentId
FROM Products f
INNER JOIN CTE c ON f.ProductId = c.ProductId) 
SELECT ROOTID,  productId  FROM CTE
WHERE ProductId <> 1;
```

The query give me this:

| ROOTID | ProductId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |

But i need to have:

| ROOTID | ProductId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2, 3, 4, 5 |

Or if i call the id 13 i expect to have:

| ROOTID | ProductId |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 6, 5 |

You can see the code running in the link below:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/615c3/77

How i can have my results but not using Cte
but converting in MySQL 5 .7

Comment: ? There is no productid 5 here

Comment: You might like my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462